# Duplicate record count for NULL fields - is there a better way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to get duplicate record count based on certain column. If field has NULL values then it is **NOT** considering as duplicate.

```
SELECT  Leadid,COUNT(Lead)
FROM    #CheckNULLCOUNT
GROUP   BY LeadId,Lead
```

but with the following query it considers as duplicate

```
 SELECT  Leadid,COUNT(ISNULL(Lead,'-'))
    FROM    #CheckNULLCOUNT
    GROUP   BY LeadId,Lead
```

**My question is there any better way to get duplicate count for NULL columns.**

```
/* Create Temporary Table*/
 CREATE table #CheckNULLCOUNT(
    Id Int PRIMARY key
    ,name varchar(100) 
    ,LeadId Int
    ,Lead varchar(100))

    /* Insert data into temporary Table*/

INSERT INTO #CheckNULLCOUNT VALUES(1,'Skip',101,'lead1')
INSERT INTO #CheckNULLCOUNT VALUES(2,'Turner',102,'lead2')
INSERT INTO #CheckNULLCOUNT VALUES(3,'Molisa',103,'lead3')
INSERT INTO #CheckNULLCOUNT VALUES(4,'Mario',104,'lead4')
INSERT INTO #CheckNULLCOUNT VALUES(5,'Jack',105,'lead5')
INSERT INTO #CheckNULLCOUNT VALUES(6,'Kris',106,'lead6')
INSERT INTO #CheckNULLCOUNT VALUES(7,'John',107,'lead7')
INSERT INTO #CheckNULLCOUNT VALUES(8,'Owen',109,NULL)
INSERT INTO #CheckNULLCOUNT VALUES(9,'Bill',109,NULL)
INSERT INTO #CheckNULLCOUNT VALUES(10,'Martin',109,NULL)
INSERT INTO #CheckNULLCOUNT VALUES(11,NULL,111,'lead9')
INSERT INTO #CheckNULLCOUNT VALUES(12,NULL,111,'lead9')

 /* **NOT** treating as duplicate */
SELECT  Leadid,COUNT(ISNULL(Lead,'-'))
FROM    #CheckNULLCOUNT
GROUP   BY LeadId,Lead


/* treating as duplicate */

SELECT  Leadid,COUNT(ISNULL(Lead,'-'))
FROM    #CheckNULLCOUNT
GROUP   BY LeadId,Lead

DROP TABLE #CheckNULLCOUNT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just

```
    SELECT  Leadid,COUNT(*)
    FROM    #CheckNULLCOUNT
    GROUP   BY LeadId,Lead
```

Comment: If we use * it will be extra burden to query.

Comment: @helloSuresh this is not true.  Count costs no more with * than with a column.  And it can be less.

Comment: @helloSuresh I guess it dont have extra cost on count... but, anyway.. should count an constant.. if you please.. like SELECT Leadid, count(3.14159265359) FROM #CheckNULLCOUNT GROUP BY LeadId,Lead

Comment: you are right. I was under impression that using * in count will be a effect performance. Will it applies if table has million rows?

Comment: @helloSuresh if I am not mistaken to execute a select count(*) from table, the sqlserver choose the narrowest index to perform the count, it doesnt gather all data from the table for count... so I realy think it will have no more costs.. and if your table have a million rows I hope its pretty well indexed. if have no index, the count should have to do a scan and then it may hurt the performance anyway..

Comment: You are right. I read same thing from other post in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  Leadid,
        COUNT(Lead) totalNOTNULL,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Lead IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalNULL
FROM    #CheckNULLCOUNT
GROUP   BY LeadId, [LEAD]
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Will there be any performance penalty if we use SUM. Just curious to know.

Comment: no, `SUM(CASE WHEN Lead IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalNULL` is the same as `COUNT(CASE WHEN Lead IS NULL THEN 1 END) totalNULL`

Comment: with your solution, we have to check in two column can we get only in column. my query SELECT  Leadid,COUNT(ISNULL(Lead,'-'))
FROM    #CheckNULLCOUNT
GROUP   BY LeadId,Lead return null/non null in column. like that.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative solution you could use this two:

```
SELECT  Leadid,COUNT(Lead)
FROM    #CheckNULLCOUNT
GROUP   BY LeadId, 
     CASE WHEN Lead IS NULL 
        THEN CAST(LeadId AS varchar(8)) 
        ELSE Lead END, Lead
```

However because of the `CAST` is not so nice. I just wanted to add to see an other idea, how can GROUP BY itself use the `CASE...WHEN`

Comment: Thanks for another solution. But I didn't get what is mean by "how can GROUP BY itself use the CASE...WHEN"

Comment: I ment, that what you generally wanted to achive: Use the GROUP BY and COUNT based on a condition, you can achive by using a condition with CASE...WHEN statement in the GROUP BY Itself.